# Graphics Issue for Lenovo g580

Tags: 13.10, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10. Everything was fine till I ran inxi and found the following -

```
System:    Host: kaustuv-Lenovo-G580 Kernel: 3.11.0-18-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 13.10
Machine:   System: LENOVO product: 2189 version: Lenovo G580
           Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID version: 31900003WIN8 STD MLT Bios: LENOVO version: 5ECN92WW(V8.04) date: 09/14/2012
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-2328M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 800.00 MHz 2: 800.00 MHz 3: 800.00 MHz 4: 800.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau,intel Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.1
Audio:     Card: Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.11.0-18-generic
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet driver: alx 
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: b8:88:e3:8b:e5:4d
           Card-2: Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter driver: wl 
           IF: eth1 state: up mac: c0:14:3d:cc:35:e1
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (75.3% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: ST500LT012 size: 500.1GB 
Partition: ID: / size: 25G used: 5.4G (23%) fs: ext4 ID: swap-1 size: 1.07GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 69.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 66.0 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 227 Uptime: 2:05 Memory: 1396.3/7849.2MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 1.9.12
```

Under the graphics section I found **FAILED: nouveau,intel** . I looked around a bit but did not find any solution sepecific to my hardware. Can anybody suggest me how I can fix this.

Thanks in advance

---

Ok...So after trying Emili's answer, my `inxi -Gff` looks like this

```
 CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-2328M CPU (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 800.00 MHz 2: 800.00 MHz 3: 800.00 MHz 4: 2200.00 MHz
           CPU Flags: acpi aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx bts clflush cmov constant_tsc 
           cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts eagerfpu epb ept est flexpriority fpu fxsr ht lahf_lm 
           lm mca mce mmx monitor msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx pae pat pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pebs 
           pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36 pts rdtscp rep_good sep ss sse sse2 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 syscall 
           tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xsave xsaveopt xtopology 
           xtpr 
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.0.0
```

And in the about this computer section it says I have "Intel® Sandybridge Mobile" running  in the graphcs section.

Now, this doesn't seem very powerful. It can't even display the 3D windows using Compiz. Or is it my graphics card is not powerful enough?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a generic graphic driver 
like bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Comment: Yup...seems to be working...although I don't know whts different... :) ...thanks for the help a lot..